# About the definition of a (completely) regular semiring

Tags: abstract-algebra, semiring

I see two definitions of a regular semiring.

**$1^{st}$ definition:** A semiring $R$ is called a regular semiring if for every $x\in R$; $x = xax$ for some $a\in R$.

**$2$nd definition:**  A semiring $(R, +, .)$ is called a completely regular semiring if every element $x$ of $R$ is completely regular. An element $x\in R$ is called a regular if there exists an element $a\in R$ such that $x= x+a+x$, $x + a = a + x$ and $a$ is called completely regular if it additionally satisfies that $x(x + a) = x + a$.

Are these two definitions of the regularity of a semiring equivalent? Also, how to define a completely regular semiring in sense of the first definition?
**Edited**
[A reference for the second definition is here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/jspui/bitstream/10603/174197/6/06_chapter%25202.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiNoKWkg4DkAhXBfX0KHScfCWEQFjABegQIDRAG&usg=AOvVaw1binZc-927zKnA3SiYnSa-)

Also, [Thesis book from where the second definition is taken](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://tubaf.qucosa.de/api/qucosa%253A22863/attachment/ATT-0/&ved=2ahUKEwiy9qvMoYDkAhU0heYKHTtRB6sQFjADegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw0XJPPS8Em1EItPEQCyoq_D)

Comment: The definition of "semiring" you are using apparently does not include commutativity of $+$?  That is unusual...

Comment: @rschwieb a reference is added. The semiring, that i am considering is a COMMUTATIV  (both additively and multiplicatively).

Comment: @rschwieb I have added the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two definitions of *regular* are obviously not equivalent.

By the second definition, *every ring* is a completely regular semiring (just let $a=-x$), but not every ring is regular in the first sense (which is also called von Neumann regularity.)

The second definition of regularity looks like it's talking about regularity of the $+$ structure, while the first is regularity of the $\cdot$ structure.

I have no clue about the condition $x(x+a)=x+a$. It is new to me.  It would help if you actually mentioned your sources.  In fact, that would be a good habit to start practicing right now...

Comment: Would you please elaborate for me as how ' not every ring is regular' in the sense of first definition?  Its seems like  every ring is regular in the sense of first definition also (just by taking $a=\frac{1}{x}$).

Comment: @gete Sure, but to do that you would need a field (or division ring). Indeed, every division ring is regular. But, for example, $\mathbb Z$ fails to be regular in the first sense.  The only regular elements are $\{0,\pm1\}$.

Comment: Yes. Also, by third condition of the second definition, we can say that every completely regular semiring is additively monoid and multiplicatively idempptent. Can't we?

Comment: @gete It seems to me you have not thought about either question, or else have not asked what you meant to ask.  $\mathbb Z$ is a completely regular semiring. Is it multiplicatively idempotent?  **Every semiring** is defined to have an underlying additive monoid, as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, you are right, and i knew that i was a bit off the topic. But, i still have a confusion regarding the definition, as it seems to me that the first definition is about regularity of '$\cdot$', while second definition is about the regularity of '$+$'. Shouldn't a regular semiring necessarily  satisfy the regularity w.r.t both the operations?  Yes, $\mathbb Z$ is a regular semiring in the sense of second definition. But, how do we show its regularity  in terms of the first definition?

Comment: @gete `how do we show its regularity in terms of the first definition?` You **can't**. $\mathbb Z$ **isn't** regular in terms of the first definition

Comment: @gete `Shouldn't a regular semiring necessarily satisfy the regularity w.r.t both the operations?` I don't know about "should" but the fact that it *doesn't* is mentioned throughout this solution and comment thread.

Comment: It's quite clear now. Thanks a lot..

Comment: @gete No problem.